# How order by neasted collection max property

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have a table with Users, and each may have many LogActivity, so there is one-to-many relation. I want to sort collection of users by their maximum property DateSearch of LogActivities (in other word users with the earliest LogActivities will be in the top). But collection of LogsActivities may be empty. The other requirement is the users should stay as IQuerable, it is important because of perfomance.

> "Invalid operation excpetion: An exception occurred while reading a database value. The expected type was 'System.DateTime' but the actual value was of type 'System.String'") and warnings ("The LINQ expression '"Max()"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally."

```
//(ToListAsync just for testing \\ identities is IQuerable<User>)

//(defaultLogsActivity is LogActivity with DateSearch = DateTime.MinValue)
var qwe = await identities.OrderBy(u => u.LogsUserActivity.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultLogsActivity))
                                .ToListAsync();// => exception("Expression of type 'UserService.Data.TDO_Models.ManagerUsers.LogsUserActivityEntity' cannot be used for parameter of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer' of method DefaultIfEmpty")

var qwe = await identities.OrderBy(u => (u.LogsUserActivity.Count != 0) ? u.LogsUserActivity.Max(l => l.DateSearch) : DateTime.MinValue )
                                .ToListAsync(); //=> exception ("Invalid operation excpetion: An exception occurred while reading a database value. The expected type was 'System.DateTime' but the actual value was of type 'System.String'") and warnings ("The LINQ expression '"Max()"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.")


 public class User{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<LogActivity> LogActivities { get; set; }
} 

public class LogActivity{
   public DateTime DateSearch { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you store dates as strings in your database, and of course they can't be implicitly cast to `DateTime`. Is this not your problem?

Comment: @John but actual type  in database (sql server) is datetime2, as long as in my model there are alse DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

It look like your have a problem casting retrieved data from database.

You can try to add to your model `[Timestamp]` or `[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]`

It should resolve your problem.

Comment: but in database (sql server) there is datetime2 type, and in my model there is DateTime

Comment: Date can be stored in dateTime, DateTime2 it just a question of precision and write/read speed

Comment: so why it may cause System.String? As in database there is datetime and in Model there is DateTime, how can it be possible? I think EF should resolve it. Isn't?

Comment: yes this is a workaround . You can open an issue in the EF official repository